# Vagrant Up or Provision if already Up

Tags: batch-file, vagrant

I need to create a simple script (Windows .bat) that will provision or up a box.

Not much experience with .bat files, so this is what I have so far:

**Edited thanks to Greg Hewgill**

```
cd C:\vagrant-box\

call vagrant-up.bat

if errorlevel 1 call vagrant-provision.bat
```

The .bat files `call`ed in the script just contain one line: `vagrant up` and `vagrant reload`, respectively.

When the vagrant box is down, then vagrant up runs successfully. When up, I encounter an error with vagrant up (which I expect) but the whole batch file dies there. `ErrorLevel` doesn't appear to do anything.

---

**Here is the error if it makes a difference**

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["list", "hostonlyifs"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to create the VirtualBox object!
VBoxManage.exe: error: Code CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE (0x80080005) - Server execution failed (extend)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Most likely, the VirtualBox COM server is not running or failed to start.
```

I want to emphasize *I don't care about the error per se*. It works when the box is not running, so it's fine. I just want to capture or ignore it, and move to the next command.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it no longer answers your edited question, and it didn't fix your problem anyway.

Comment: why do you need to call it? Whats wrong with the `start` command

Comment: @GregHewgill Well thanks anyway it was helpful if not exactly an *answer*. The jist was: "`if errorlevel 0` evaluates to `true` if the `errorlevel` is *greater than or equal to 0*, so change it to `if errorlevel 1`".

Comment: @Monacraft What `start` command? I'm not aware of `vagrant start`, is it a windows batch command? If so, will it let me examine the `errorlevel` to branch the command?

Comment: From your description, it would appear that `vagrant` is not terminating if the box is already up. What happen if you executed `vagrant up` directly from the prompt while the vagrant box is up? Would there be a `vagrant` executable loaded if the box is up?

Comment: The error occurs when running `vagrant up` while the box is up. If the box is down, it boots up with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vagrant up` exits with code 0 even if the machine is already running.

But you don't have to bother with exit codes, you can just run:

```
vagrant provision && vagrant up
```

And you should cover both cases. If the guest is not running, `vagrant provision` will gracefully fail and `vagrant up` will succeed, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your vagrant-up.bat.

Also, try either this:
`vagrant up --debug`

and/or

`VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant <action>`

To get more detais about the COM/VBox issue.